# Apache2 read home folder directory when main domain is in /var/www

Tags: apache2, home-directory, virtualhost, www

I am setting a lab for students to create webpages this is the setup I currently have:
I am a little new to setting up a web server, so please bear with me :-)

OS - Ubuntu 14.04, Apache main domain in `/var/www/<name of domain>`, conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Now I have setup a user account with this structure `/home/<username>/public_html`

I want to create an URL like this : `http://<domain>/~<username>`

My current virtual host is:

```
 <Virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName default.only
 <Location />
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 </Location>
 Redirect permanent / https://bcs.net.nz/s/
 </Virtualhost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@bcs.net.nz
            ServerName bcs.net.nz
            ServerAlias www.bcs.net.nz

            DocumentRoot /var/www/bcs.net.nz/s/


            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine On

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>


<VirtualHost 172.16.1.102:80 192.168.1.9:80>
ServerAdmin admin@bcs.net.nz
ServerName bcs.net.nz
ServerAlias www.bcs.net.nz
DocumentRoot /var/www/bcs.net.nz/


    <Directory /var/www/bcs.net.nz>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS|HEAD)
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

    </Directory>

    ServerSignature off
    AliasMatch ^/parallel/propulsion(.*) "/var/www/bcs.net.nz/parallel/index.html"
    AliasMatch ^/parallel/(.*) "/var/www/bcs.net.nz/parallel/index.html"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ProxyBlock *
 </VirtualHost>
```

I need to resolve the URL, but since the files are not in `/var/www/` but the main domain is, I am a little stuck as to how to change the above virtual host file for this.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: “bear with me,” is a request for forbearance or patience. “Bare with me” would be an invitation to undress.  **;-)**

Comment: Yeah that is the price you for having english as a second language - I am not always smooth on the right saying. Also english is confusing at the best of times, but that is a story for another Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: Kein Problem! Geen probleem!  ;-) (Looking at the name I only can deduce these two native languages)

Comment: The second one :-)

Comment: Could still be Afrikaans, Dutch or Flemish!  >:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

on the command line to enable the Apache module [mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html) and make sure `/home/<username>/public_html` is accessible for the webserver.

Comment: Ok the module was already enabled - and chmod 755 should be fine for the accessibility right?

Comment: `/home/` and `/home/<username>` need to have exec permissions for "others", too. If it doesn't work: Do you get any error messages in `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`?

Comment: ok I am a little further - the log is about 20 minutes behind, so it must be picking up any errors as such. But I double checked the permissions so that got me a bit further. I just need to see the files. Thanks